# Master-detail Angular Material example

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would be very grateful if someone could help me in the following example of an **Angular Material** ‘rich’ table, in which, by clicking on any of its records, you can access the detailed view of it.

In this detail view two buttons are provided to go to the previous and subsequent table registration.

That navigation works correctly, even if it has been paginated on the table; except if, **filtering** or **sorting** occurs on the table.

Key resources are:

- factura.service service
- tabla-facturas component
- detalle-factura component

Could someone help me with the navigation functionality in the detail view, so that it works in all cases, whether the main table has been sorted, filtered, paged, etc?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ej-test1-pub

https://angular-ej-test1-pub.stackblitz.io/tablaFacturas

Comment: What do you want in this? I didn't find the question here?

Comment: I edited with this question: Could someone help me with the navigation functionality in the detail view, so that it works in all cases, whether the main table has been sorted, filtered, paged, etc?

Comment: Is your stackblitz working? I can just see a header and footer label

Comment: You have to add tablaFacturas to the uRL: https://angular-ej-test1-pub.stackblitz.io/tablaFacturas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make changes in following files:

1. factura.service.ts service

   add one variable to store filtered or sorted data.

```
filteredFacturas: Array<Factura>;
```

2. tabla-facturas.component.ts component

   add below code after you initialize MatTableDataSource in component.ts to get sorted and filtered data from data table

```
this.facturas.connect().subscribe((data) => {
  this.facturaService.filteredFacturas = data;
});
```

3. detalle-factura.component.ts component

   change

```
  this.facturaService.arrayFacturas
```

to

```
  this.facturaService.filteredFacturas
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, I've been on vacation. Could you please clarify exactly where the block you indicate in point 2 goes?

Comment: after `this.facturas = new MatTableDataSource<Factura>(facturas);` line

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong. After pagination nothing works. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ej-test2-pub

Comment: After commenting this line it seems to work:  //posicion = posicion + (this.facturas.paginator.pageIndex * this.facturas.paginator.pageSize);